# chrome extension - manifest version 2

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that has a  reference to the jquery file.
this is my popup html (only the head tag):

```
<head>
    <title>My Extention</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.MySite.com/Resources/JS/JQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyExtensionScript.js"></script>
</head>
```

so in "MyExtensionScript.js" i thought i could use jquery but apparently the $ function is not defined.
This is my manifest.json file:

```
{
  "name": "My Test Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test version of My Extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "test.ico",
    "default_popup": "Test.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

in version 1 of the manifest it worked, but now it doesn't. I tried to use the "web_accessible_resources" and add to them "http://www.MySite.com/Resources/JS/JQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" but that didn't work also. any ideas?
also, i have a script injected to the current page and returning me a message (in my case some html source of the current page), will this behavior be affected by the transition to manifest version 2?
Thanks all :)

**EDIT:** I have a web application that enables cross domain scripting (using JSONP). In my extension i had a script calling a web service in my site with $.getJSON. now it doesn't work. i'm pretty sure that it has to do with the new manifest version but how can i enable again the cross domain scripting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a jQuery file stored locally in your extension, rather than referenced from your site.

This is due to Chrome's strict [Content Security Policy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) that only allows local scripts to be executed, with no inline code.

[Web Accessible Resources](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources) are files **inside your extension** that may be accessed from the web, rather that resources your extension can access that are on the web. For example, if you wanted to change the background image of a page using an image stored in the extension, you have to add that image to the list in `web_accessible_resouces` in your manifest.

The change of manifest version should not affect your content scripts, unless they do something that is no longer allowed. You can see what else has changed from the Chrome [manifestVersion](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html) docs.

Comment: https resources can be whitelisted, but it's still recommended to package the script with the extension.

Comment: @RobW - how can i whitelist http resources and why is it still recommended to package the scripts with the extension?

Comment: @GilTankus `http` resources cannot be whitelisted (hence I said "https"). Re packaging: Imagine that the user is disconnected from the internet. Then, your extension won't work when the resources are external.

Comment: @Robw - Thanks a lot for the explanation. I agree and i packaged all my resources in the extension folder. Any thoughts on how i can send from my extension a request to my server (my server supports cross domain scripting - JSONP) using $.getJSON?

Comment: @GilTankus JSONP cannot be used, but within a Chrome extension, you can make cross-origin requests when you've whitelisted the URL in the manifest file, at the permissions section.

Comment: @RobW - i have in my manifest the permission "<all_urls>". does this not take care of this? so i can't use the $.getJSON function like i did in manifest version 1 on urls like `"http://www.mysite.com/restful/service/name?callback=?"`?

Comment: @GilTankus JSONP appends a `<script>` element to the document. Because of the [Content Security policy](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html), external scripts may not be loaded. Just use the JSON version of the webservice, or manually parse the result.

Comment: OK - JSONP is possible in the new manifest version. need to run application on https and add the domain to the white list in the content_security_policy of the manifest.json, after this, you can send jsonp requests and get the results back.

Comment: I have an extension with the same problem, but I have the jQuery file in the extension folder. The problem is that it works locally in development mode, but when I deploy the extension to the WebStore, the installation fails.

Answer (score 1):

I just include jquery in my content scripts. just make sure to load it before your script.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "default_title": "Babble",
  "version": "1.2",
  "description": "Chat in your language with friends in their language",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "default_icons": {
    "16": "img/icon16.png",
    "48": "img/icon48.png",
    "128": "img/icon128.png"
  },

  "content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches": ["http://mail.google.com/*", "https://mail.google.com/*"],
        "css" : ["css/style.css"],
        "js" : ["js/jquery.js" , "js/translate.js" , "js/jquery.cookie.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```