# JS wont run in extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Im making a Chrome extension and the java script wont run when I try the extension in chrome 
but it works fine if i open it in a regular tab.

The only thing that is supposed to happen is that there should be a log in the console
and an alert when the button is clicked.

the popup.html file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Enter key word</h1>
    <input id="input" type="text">
    <input id ="keyWord" type="submit" value="Hide the thingy"/>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The extjs.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    console.log("sdfsdfsdfsdfs");
    $("#keyWord").click(function(){

        var input = document.getElementById("input");
        console.log(input);
        console.log("sdfsdfsdfsdfs");
        alert("sdfsdfsdf");

    });
});
```

the manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hello World!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Chrome extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Comment: as this is an extension you'd be a lot better off including a downloaded version of jQuery with your extension, so it is available even when offline.

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome extension - manifest version 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814270/chrome-extension-manifest-version-2)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the way you are loading jQuery from the external CDN violates the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). To fix this you can download jquery, place it in the extension directory, and load it with `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>`.

Comment: Also, the problem is not debugging the extension; [here's a guide to debugging a popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) that would've shown the error and pointed OP in the right direction.